# Present UINavigationController from UITabBarController tab root view

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'd like to present a navigation controller from a tab bar controller's tab's root view controller and have the tabs from the tab bar controller visible.

Here's a photo of an example storyboard: 
[image]

The tab bar controller has a relationship to the `ItemOneViewController`, which is implemented like this:

```
import UIKit

class ItemOneViewController: UIViewController {

  private func presentNavigationController() {

    let id = "NavController"
    guard let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: id) else { return }

    present(vc, animated: true)
  }

  override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    presentNavigationController()
  }
}
```

I hoped that by presenting the navigation controller from the root view controller of a tab on a tab bar controller that the navigation controller would be presented behind the tabs, but when I run the described app, this is what the simulator looks like:

[image]

This is what the view hierarchy looks like:

[image]

I think I remember a previous colleague mentioning that a `UINavigationController` will replace the view stack, which makes sense but is there anyway to keep it or bring the `UITabBarController` with it?

I've tried adjusting the presentation style and context but haven't had any luck.

Comment: why you are not assigning **NavController** to the UITabBarController root view controller?

Comment: @NikunjKumbhani because the requirement is that the view controller that is the tab bar's root controller is not a navigation controller.

Comment: Please check my answer  you need to embed **ItemOneViewController** with navigation controller so you can bring that with **UITabBarItem** as well as **UINavigationController**

Answer (score 0):

Try embedding your ItemOneViewController in Navigation Controller instead of embedding you ViewController VC in Navigation Controller.

Comment: @Fred Faust gave us a code example to work with. Giving advise is good, but giving an example based on your advise is much better. Please provide your answer with an example

Comment: @DerkJanSpeelman thank you for the answer but ItemOneViewController cannot be embedded in a navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

Select **ItemOneViewController** from storyboard.

Go to the Editor and Embed with Navigation Controller

[image]

Your view hierarchy at Storyboard looks Like this :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the requirement is that the tab bar's root tab view controller cannot be a navigation controller.

Comment: @FredFaust Then it's not possible to display tab in the presented view controller. If you want to navigate anywhere with the bottom tab bar then must embade with NavigationController.

Comment: I think you're correct, the only way for me to do what I want may be to make ItemOne embedded in a navigation controller and hide it's nav bar, then do a push without animation for the next VC and add a custom transition between the two.

Comment: @FredFaust Yes, Excetly